# Set Due Date in Asana Task from Wufoo Form

Tags: asana, wufoo

I have a Wufoo form that, when submitted, creates a new Asana task.

Is there a way to make a "date" field in a Wufoo form automatically set the **Due Date** in an Asana task? My guess is that there would be a CSS layout keyword for it, but perhaps it doesn't exist.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I work at Asana)

We haven't added this functionality yet but hope to in the near future - it is one of our top requests for the Wufoo integration.  I'll make a note to update this task when we add it.